# Find the series solution about $x=0$ of the following differential equation $x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}-(x^2+\frac 54)y=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the series solution about $x=0$ (using the method of Frobenius) of the following differential equation: $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}-(x^2+\frac 54)y=0.$$

Write the first three non-zero terms in each series and hence, find the general solution of the equation.

I tried solving this problem as follows( Using method of Frobenius):

Given, $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}-(x^2+\frac 54)y=0.$$

We note that $x=0$ is a regular singular point of this differential equation. Hence we assume that the power series solution around this $x_0=0$ is of the form $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x)^{n+r}.$

We hereby find that, $$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_n(x)^{n+r-1}$$ and $$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r-2}.$$

Substituting these values of the derivatives so obtained, in the given equation, we have, $$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}-(x^2+\frac 54)y=0\implies x^2(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r-2})-x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_n(x)^{n+r-1}-x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x)^{n+r}-\frac 54\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x)^{n+r}=0\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)(n+r-1)c_nx^{n+r}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)c_n(x)^{n+r}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_{n-2}(x)^{n+r}-\frac 54\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x)^{n+r}=0\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\big [(n+r)(n+r-1)c_n-(n+r)c_n(x)-c_{n-2}-\frac 54c_n\big ]x^{n+r}+r(r-1)c_0+(r+1)(r)xc_1-rc_0-(r+1)xc_1-\frac 54 c_1x-\frac 54c_0=0.$$

From here, we again have, the indicial equation as $r^2-2r-\frac 54=(2r+1)(2r-5)=0,$ which means the exponents of this differential equation is $r_1=\frac 52,r_2=-\frac 12.$

Also, $(r^2-\frac 94)c_1=0\implies c_1=0.$

Now, the recurrence relation, after some re arrangement and simplifications is , $$[4(n+r)(n+r-1)-4(n+r)-5]c_n=4c_{n-2},\forall n\geq 2.$$

Using the value of $r=r_1=\frac 52$ and substituting this in the above recurrence relation and then simplifying the expression, we finally get, $$c_n=\frac{c_{n-2}}{n(n+3)},n\geq 2.$$

If $n=2$, then $c_2=\frac{c_0}{10},$

If $n=3$, then $c_3=0$ as $c_1=0$ and consequently all odd coefficients are $0.$

If $n=4$ then, $c_4=\frac{c_2}{28}=\frac{c_0}{280},$ and so on.

Using this relations we have, $y=y_1(x)=c_0+c_1+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4+\cdots=c_0(1+\frac {x^2}{10}+\frac{x^4}{280}+\cdots)$

Now, for the other solution, we try to emulate this same abive process but now using $r=r_2=-\frac 12.$

Using this, the recurrence relation, is $$[4(n+r)(n+r-1)-4(n+r)-5]c_n=4c_{n-2},\forall n\geq 2,$$ turns out to be, $$c_{n}=\frac{c_{n-2}}{n(n-3)},\forall n\geq 2,$$ using some necessary algebraic rearrangements.

Now, as $c_1=0$ so, all the odd coefficients in this case are $0$ as well.

Also, if $n=2$ then $c_2=-\frac{c_0}{2}$

If $n=4$ then $c_4=\frac{-c_0}{8},$
and so on.

Using these relations, we have, $y=c_0+c_1+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4+\cdots=c_0(1-\frac {x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+\cdots),$ but this is nothing but a constant multiple of $y_1(x),$ which means that this expression is not linearly independent of $y_1(x).$

In order to find a linearly independent solution  $y_2(x)$ we apply the method of order of reduction, which states that:

If $a_0(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=F(x)$ is a second order linear (ordinary) differential equation,  and $f(x)$ is a solution of this equation, then another solution linearly independent of $f(x)$ is given by  $y=f(x)\int\big(\frac{e^{-\int\frac{a_0(x)}{a_1(x)}}}{[f(x)]^2}\big ).$

Using this, we consider $f(x)=y_{11}(x)$ where $y_{11}(x)=y_1(x)$ with $c_0=1.$

Now, $$y(x)=y_2(x)=y_{11}(x)\int\big(\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}{[y_{11}(x)]^2}\big ).$$

Hence, the general solution  is $y=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x).$

---

However, the point is in the question it was given, "Write the first three non-zero terms in each series," but it seems the integral $$y(x)=y_2(x)=y_{11}(x)\int\big(\frac{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}{[y_{11}(x)]^2}\big ),$$ is difficult to evaluate.

I want to know if my solution is valid to the point or not, and how to find the second linearly independent solution, in power series representation. Have I made some mistake?

Comment: How did you conclude that the first version of $y_2$ is a constant multiple of $y_1$? They look quite different, starting with the signs. And you did not apply the factor $x^r$ in both cases.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah, that's the mistake. That's a silly error I did. Any suggestions how to be good at these calculations?